# How can I merge two Firestore queries to pass as Options on Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to merge 2 queries to pass them as Options to display on my FirestoreRecyclerView. All the methods I found would merge only the Tasks and therefore I can pass the task on setQuery. Below is my query1 and query2 and I need to merge them in one query to display. How can I achieve this?

```
        val query1 = firestoreRepo.getAllGames()
            .whereEqualTo(Constants.PLAYER1ID, currentUserID)
            .whereEqualTo("player2Id", argsId)
    
        val query2 = firestoreRepo.getAllGames().whereEqualTo("player2Id", currentUserID)
            .whereEqualTo("player1Id", argsId)


        val options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Games> = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Games>()
            .setQuery(query, Games::class.java)
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .build()
```

[Games DataClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G1J7.png)

[Games Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA2SH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot pass two queries to FirestorePagingOptions, only one is allowed. If you need the result of two queries, then you should use [Tasks.whenAllSuccess()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAllSuccess(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...)) method, like in the following lines of code:

```
val query1 = firestoreRepo.getAllGames()
    .whereEqualTo(Constants.PLAYER1ID, currentUserID)
    .whereEqualTo("player2Id", argsId)

val query2 = firestoreRepo.getAllGames()
    .whereEqualTo("player2Id", currentUserID)
    .whereEqualTo("player1Id", argsId)

val firstTask = query1.get()
val secondTask = query2.get()

val combinedTask: Task<*> = Tasks.whenAllSuccess<Any>(firstTask, secondTask).addOnSuccessListener {
    //Do what you need to do with your list
}
```

When overriding the onSuccess() method, the result is a list of objects. Because both queries return objects of type `Games`, you can simply cast the objects from the list to objects of type `Games`. In that case, you won't be able to use the Firebase-UI library anymore. Not perfect, but it will do the trick.

Comment: I tried this method but I'm still having problems displaying the items on the recycler view. I added  ```val gamesMutableList : List<Games> = it.filterIsInstance<Games>()
                gamesList.addAll(gamesMutableList)
        }``` to cast the List<Any> to my class Games and add it to gameList to be displayed but it is not working

Comment: In that case, please add a screenshot of your database and the content of your Games class.

Comment: I added both screenshots. When I tried with only one query, the recyclerview was displaying all right. I changed the FIrestoreAdapter to a regular adapter and I need to display the gamesList

Comment: Are you sure you have in the database at least a document that satisfies **both** conditions? I'm afraid you don't. Besides that, I think a single query would be enough to get a document like the one in the screenshot.

Comment: The idea is that both Player1 and Player2 can enter the game result and it will be displayed for both. If a user input the result it will be stored as Player1Id and the opponent as Player2Id, but if the opponent inputs it, it will be the opposite. That is why I need to retrieve them both

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have in the database at least a document that satisfies both conditions?

Comment: 100%. I entered a game result with Player1 and a game result with Player2, each game is recorded with the ID of the user who inputed it as PlayerID1

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the exact ids in both queries?

Comment: I'm sure. The query I need would be in SQL like ```SELECT * FROM games WHERE (playerId1 = currentUserId AND playerId2 = argsId) OR (playerId2 = currentUserId AND playerId2 = argsId)``` and then load it automatically in my recyclerVIew. I can do it only with one part of the query. With a method I found in your website I was able to achieve it in a differente way but also with only one query, I can't merge the two of them to display everything as Games object

Comment: As long as you have the database documents that satisfy your query and the ids are correct, then that list should contain those objects.

Comment: But how do I cast the result of the combinedTask into a Games object? The lambda expression gives me a List<Any> and I need to convert it into a List<Games>. With one Task I used this ```val firstTask = query1.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val document: QuerySnapshot? = task.result
                    val games: List<Games> =
                        document?.toObjects(Games::class.java) as List<Games>
                        gamesList.addAll(games)
                }
            }``` but on the combined it does not work

Comment: No, not like that. You should iterate the list of objects and cast each object to an object of type Games, ok?

Comment: Yes, I finally did it. After trying a bunch of work arounds, I created an extra field of player = player1 + "_" + player2 and then queried it with a whereIn clause

Comment: Good to hear that ;)